# Rename & Renumbering by increment in files - Need batch file

Tags: macos, batch-file, cmd

I need to rename & renumber multiple files with Increment.

Example, i have some files...

```
per29958_ch01_002-029.pdf
per29958_ch02_030-055.pdf
per29958_ch03_056-085.pdf
```

i need to renumber and rename this as

```
01_Test_ch01_002-029.pdf
02_Test_Ch02_030_055.pdf
03_Test_Ch03_056_085.pdf
```

i have used this cmd file, in this i can rename the files, but i couldnt able to add the number infront of new files...

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET old=per29958
SET new=Test

for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.pdf') do (
  SET newname=%%f
  SET newname=!newname:%old%=%new%!
  move "%%f" "!newname!"
)
```

Pls anyone help me to add the number in prefix with increment....

Comment: Why is this tagged with [osx] ?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to count from 100 and strip the first digit:

```
...
set count=100
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.pdf') do (
  set /a count+=1
  set "newname=!count:~1!_Test"
  ...
```